# How to fix "TERM environment variable not set" when clearing console using Python code?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I use Pycharm and when I run this Python code

```py
os.system("clear")
```

I get this error:

> TERM environment variable not set

In the Python Console, in the variables, I put

```
export TERM = xterm
```

What else can I do?

Comment: If anything it should be `export TERM=xterm` (no spaces around `=`), but I'm not sure that pycharm's terminal does realy support this

Comment: I check spaces and there are ok

Answer (score 20):

Try this configuration, i found it very helpful after struggling finding the solution and after configure the correct TERM variable.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is a simple solution for this.
You need to go to the 'Run/Debug configuration'
You can do this by going to 'Run' and selecting Edit configuration option on the title bar.

Then you can go to the environment variable option to add the environment variable 'TERM' and set the value as 'xterm-color'

you can check it out on this website.
http://softwaretester.info/pycharm-term-environment-variable-not-set/

Comment: That doesn't really help. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56306486/2648551 for an explanation. You can emulate the terminal as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65161315/2648551) here.