# os.system('cls') doesn't clear the screen in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, cls

I use `os.system('cls')` in Pycharm to clear the screen from what has been printed before. However, when running the code, it does not clear the formerly printed stuff, and instead prints an upward arrow at the end. What can the problem be?

Comment: could you try os.system("clear")

Comment: Does typing `cls` to the terminal (outside of the Python interactive interpreter) clear the formerly printed stuff? `cls` only works on Windows, use `clear` for Unix

Answer (score 8):

PyCharm's emulation of the Windows system console isn't 100%. Neither is any IDE's. Try that in IDLE or PythonWin, and you will see that it also does something other than you might expect from the Windows console.

This behaviour is by design. Bear in mind that most real-world Python interactive applications do not interact with their users via `input()` and `print()` calls.

If you want your output to behave exactly like the Windows console then send your output to the Windows console.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the terminal to emulate your OSs terminal, you have to edit the 'Run/Debug Configuration' and tick the box 'Emulate terminal in output console'.

Then `os.system("cls")` will clear the screen on Windows and `os.system("clear")` on unix

Comment: Just to add to this, you can use `os.system('cls || clear')` for portability. This should work for Windows, Linux, and MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
print('\n'*80)
```

Not perfect but works.