# How to clear the output time to time using function in PyCharm

Tags: python

I want to clear the screen time to time using function in Pycharm. When I tried to run the commands continuously, the screen gets full and seems clumsy.

I've tried the following commands used for CMD Mode and it is not working with Pycharm.

```
def clear():
    os.system('cls')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [os.system('cls') doesn't clear the screen in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306486/os-systemcls-doesnt-clear-the-screen-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, Pycharm has no clear screen for it's console.

Whenever you restart the script that is running, the console will be cleared.

You can also do something like this,
`print('\n'*80) # prints 80 line breaks`, to emulate clearing the screen