# replit.clear() or os.system('cls') doesn't work in pycharm, what else to use?

Tags: python, pycharm

This my code. I tried clear() and os.system('cls') and Ipython function , but they didn't work. What else to clear output on the console to get newest input data? Is anything wrong in my code? But I didn't recognize error in my code.

```
from random import randint
import os


def play_the_game():
    guess_number()
    if input("Do you want to play again? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
        os.system('cls')
        play_the_game()
    else:
        print("Bye.")


def guess_number():
    print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!\nI'm thinking a number between 1 and 100.")
    level = input("Choose a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ").lower()

    if level == "hard":
        print("You have 5 attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        life = 5
    else:
        print("You have 10 attempts remaining to guess the number.")
        guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
        life = 10

    number = randint(0, 100)
    while life > 0:
        if guess > 100 or guess < 0:
            guess = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100. Try again: "))
        if guess > number:
            life -= 1
            print(f"Too high.\nGuess again.")
            if life == 0:
                print("You've run out of guesses. You lose.")
            else:
                print(f"You have {life} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
                guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))

        elif guess < number:
            life -= 1
            print(f"Too low.\nGuess again.")
            if life == 0:
                print("You've run out of guesses. You lose.")
            else:
                print(f"You have {life} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
                guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))

        else:
            print(f"You got it! The answer is {guess}.")
            life = 0


play_the_game()
```

Comment: Try "clear" instead of cls;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [os.system('cls') doesn't clear the screen in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306486/os-systemcls-doesnt-clear-the-screen-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm goto Run->Edit Configurations->Edit configuration templates->python. Under execution check emulate terminal in output console

Comment: This answer is [already present on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60952869/14122) [proposed by moken last August](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76938269/replit-clear-or-os-systemcls-doesnt-work-in-pycharm-what-else-to-use?noredirect=1#comment135632329_76938269). Note the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".