"Why aren't the outputs being cleared in the code?"
i wrote this code i the output didn't cleared
import os
def clear_screen():
    # Check if Operating System is Mac and Linux or Windows
    if os.name == 'posix':
        _ = os.system('clear')
    else:
        _ = os.system('cls')
def display_numbers():
    for i in range(1, 6):
        print(f"Displaying numbers up to {i * 10}")
        for number in range(1, i * 10 + 1):
            print(number, end=' ', flush=True)
        print("\n")
        input("Press Enter to clear the screen and show the next sequence...")
        clear_screen()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    display_numbers()

I'm sure the code is correct because no programming errors appeared. Is the problem with the Linux operating system, missing something in the OS, or is it an issue with PyCharm? I'm really confused.

Tested your code in both PyCharm and terminal on Linux Mint, and it does clear the screen for me. Does the clear part work for you in python shell?

Add some kind of print() to "if" and "else" and check if it met the condition.

No, the code works correctly and nothing is wrong with it. What are you expecting? The screen is cleared and updated each iteration.

Add wait time to see how the screen get cleared after clear_screen() line   like time.sleep(1)  # Adjust time  

yes it work it work in the terminal but not in Pycharm

There is already an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56306881/23456704

os.system will spawn a new shell everytime , you output is on STDOUT , clear_screen spawns a new shell and clears the content

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
